# WPF LayoutUpdated event handler not working for maximize

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, width

I want my `MenuBar` to scale its width according to width of the Window.

I wrote following code.

```
private void Window_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Window x = (Window)proj.App.Current.MainWindow;
    menu1.Width = x.Width;
}
```

It works well for manual scaling of the window. But when I maximize it, the menu bar does not change the size. Is there some other event handler for those events?

Answer (score 1):

It was pretty simple. For those who want to know, it is the `ActualWidth` property of x that I needed to use. `ActualWidth` will actually read the new width rather than using the stored value. So it gets fired upon maximization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Size changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged.aspx) event of Window to find out when the window size is changed.

If you want to know when window is minimized or maximized you can handle [state changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.onstatechanged.aspx) event

Comment: OK. I have figured it out. LayoutUpdated is ok. All I had to change was to use ActualWidth instead.